# MySQL migration FROM SQL Server convert bit to bit instead of tinyint

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration

I have plenty of tables with SQL Server `bit`-type fields. When I run these through the MySQL Migration Toolkit, it seems by default they're converted to `tinyint`. This sucks for my code, because it's expecting true/false and it's getting possible values of 0-255.

Any idea where to change this conversion step in the migration toolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by not migrating everything live. Migration Toolkit allows for scripting the create and insert SQL statements. Modified these in Notepad++ and imported via PHPMyAdmin